# Error message Define the main method as Public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: java

Hi I'm new to java and facing the below error

i'm trying to run this script

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class Demo { 
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\javacoding\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://google.com");
    }
}
```

But get this error when i try to run it

> Error: Main method not found in class Demo, please define the main
>   method as:    public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX
>   application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: The code should work fine, are you sure you're using the code from teh snippet provided?

Comment: `or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application` maybe? 
something like `public class Demo extends javafx.application.Application` ? (or just Application, but be sure you will import correct file)

Comment: What is your package structure ?

Answer (score 0):

In the `public static void Main()`
gives the error:

```
Error: Main method not found in class Main1
```

define the main method as:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

or a JavaFX application class must extend `application.Applicationjavafx`

if you change capital `M` to small `m` in main the error will not occur

Answer (score -1):

Regarding the [docs with example](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm) and as error message says

> Error: Main method not found in class Demo, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args) *or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application*

The main is in place, but inheritance not, you will need to extend `javafx.application.Application`, so assuming that should fix the issue:

replace the class declaration as `public class Demo` to `public class Demo extends javafx.application.Application`

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Demo extends javafx.application.Application{ 
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\javacoding\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://google.com");
    }
}
```

Or just `public class Demo` to `public class Demo extends Application` with `import javafx.application.Application;` (in the import section of the class)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import javafx.application.Application; //added 


public class Demo extends Application{ 
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\javacoding\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://google.com");
    }
}
```

It seems you did not created the correct type of the project in your IDE, maybe re-creation will be needed (like eg. in case of maven project you need some additional files like pom.xml, etc.)

Comment: Is it a javaFx application?